# QGIS: Snapping QGIS stopped working

Tags: qgis, snapping

Suddenly snapping stopped working correctly and no longer follows the rules I set, "sticking" to distant or even non-existent vertices/segments. Even if I change the parameters (layer to be snapped onto, tolerance, topological modification, intersections, vertex/segments, SR equal for project and all layers, etc.) the result does not change. I tried all combinations. At this point I have transferred the layer where I am creating the polygons to a new project and the snapping works but only on that layer, if I try to apply the snapping to another layer (obviously selecting it in the parameters) the situation returns as before and the snapping is useless.
[image]

Comment: It looks like you've tried a lot of what I would look at.  You might post a snapshot of your snapping settings for others to see.  Did you also check the geometry of your layers?  If all else fails you can always reset your application by renaming your app data folder (C:\Users\yourusernamehere\AppData\Roaming\QGIS) and see if a new one fixes things.  If not rename it back (to get back any customizations) and look elsewhere.

Comment: What format is your datasource? In my experience, shapefiles (.shp) can produce all kinds of quirky (and undesired) behaviour in digitizng (snapping, etc.) tools.